# How to Prove by Induction, inductive hypothesis

Tags: logic, induction

During proof by induction, for the inductive hypothesis part, do you use S(x) or k+1, my teacher uses S(x), the successor of x, but every video online uses k+1.

So for proof by induction over c. "P(x) = (a+b)+c = a+(b+c)"

Would the inductive hypothesis be "(a+b)+s(x) = a+(b+s(x))" or "(a+b)+(k+1) = a+(b+(k+1))"

And for the s(x) method what would we use to prove the hypothesis, as i know for the k+1 method we substitute k into the original equation (over c) and work to prove the hypothesis that way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have used the [tag:solution-verification] tag. Which solution do you want us to verify?

Comment: Are you using some kind of formal system where `S` is a primitive? In standard mathematical reasoning, `S(k)` and `k+1` are the same thing.

Comment: For proof by induction over c. "(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)"                                                                         Is the inductive hypothesis: (a+b)+(k+1) = a+(b+(k+1))    or    (a+b)+s(x) = a+(b+s(x))?

Comment: No difference at all... You can use either $k$ or $n$ as variable and thus your property will be either $P(k)$ or $P(n)$.

Comment: For the induction step, you have to assume $P(k)$ and prove $P(k+1)$ [or the same with $n$] and no change either if you assume $P(k)$ and prove $P(s(k))$ [also used $P(k')$].